# How to specify frame size in class with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've learning tkinter and i want use place to specify button position but place is not working. I know i have to specify frame size but i don't know how to do it in class.

```
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.new = tk.Button(self)
        self.new['height'] = 10
        self.new['width'] = 20
        self.new['text'] = 'button'
        self.new['bg'] = 'red'
        self.new.place(x=0, y=0)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1280x720')
root.resizable(False, False)
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for @Hepii?

```py
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, x, y, width, height, title, face):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.config(bg = 'black')
        self.place(x = x, y = y, width = width, height = height)
        self.create_widgets(width-20, height-20, title, face)

    def create_widgets(self, width, height, title, face):
        self.new = tk.Button(self, text = title, bg = face)
        self.new.place(x = 10, y = 10, width = width, height = height)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1280x720')
root.resizable(False, False)

# row 1
apA = App(root, 0,   0, 200, 100, 'buttonA', 'red')
apB = App(root, 220, 0, 200, 100, 'buttonB', 'orange')
apC = App(root, 440, 0, 200, 100, 'buttonC', 'yellow')

# row 2
apD = App(root, 0,   110, 200, 100, 'buttonD', 'cyan')
apE = App(root, 220, 110, 200, 100, 'buttonE', 'green')
apF = App(root, 440, 110, 200, 100, 'buttonF', 'magenta')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, size=(0, 0), **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, width=size[0], height=size[1], **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.new = tk.Button(self, height=10, width=20, text="button", bg="red")
        self.new.place(x=0, y=0)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1280x720')
root.resizable(False, False)
app = App(root, (100, 100), bg="blue")
app = App(root, (500, 500), bg="green")
app.mainloop()
```

I passed in the `width` and `height` parameters when creating the frame. I also added `bg="blue"` and `bg="green"` to show the part of the frame that isn't being covered by the button.

If you are going to `.pack` widgets inside the frame then you will need call `self.pack_propagate(False)`. And if you are going to call `.grid` on the widgets inside the frame you will need to call `self.grid_propagate(False)`

Also please note that calling `self.pack()` isn't a good practise. It's better to call `app.pack()` from outside the class.

Comment: It doesn't increase size if you change parameters

Comment: @PCM I updated my answer. The problem is that the frame's colour was the same as the `root`'s colour. So you couldn't see its real size. The only thing you saw was the button's size (the red rectangle)

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I was talking about your answer before you added `.pack-propagate`

Comment: @PCM The `.pack_propagate` only applies when you are calling `.pack` on the widgets inside the frame. In this case OP is only calling `.place` on the widgets inside the frame.